# Xwrapper.config ignored on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, xorg

Installed ubuntu, using network install, xorg and openbox.

```
/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config:

allowed_users=anybody

/etc/systemd/system/kiosk.service

 [Unit]
 Description=Kiosk Launcher
 # After=systemd-user-sessions.service

 [Service]
 # if this line is disabled x starts else not
 User=kioskuser
 ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'startx'

 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target



 # from an ssh login
 kioskuser@pc:~$ startx

 (==) Log file: "/home/tmil/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Sep 10 10:48:24 2018
 (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
 (EE) 
 Fatal server error:
 (EE) parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (Permission denied)

 (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to install `xserver-xorg-legacy` and add those lines to `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.conf`

```
allowed_users=anybody
needs_root_rights=yes
```

This way `X` finally started and within `/home/kioskuser/.xsession` I added more code to setup openbox as well.